# Using NAudio to play a WAV with custom codec

Tags: c#, wav, codec, naudio

I have a WAV file that has been recorded using a custom codec. The codec has been installed on my machine, and the WAV file plays fine on my machine using Windows Media player. I am using the NAudio routines to try and play the WAV file via some C# code. The values for the custom format look weird, but I have painstakingly checked them by analysing the WAV file header. Here is the best C# code I have come up with for playing the file:

```
WaveFormat wfOKI = WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat(WaveFormatEncoding.DialogicOkiAdpcm, 8000, 1, 3000, 48, 3);
WaveStream wsRaw = new WaveFileReader(txtFileName.Text);
wsRaw = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(wsRaw);    // Line A
wsRaw = new BlockAlignReductionStream(wsRaw);                 // Line B
WaveStream wsOKI = new RawSourceWaveStream(wsRaw, wfOKI);

WaveOut woCall = new WaveOut();
woCall.Init(wsOKI);    // <-- This line gives an error.
woCall.Play();

while (woCall.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

The Init() causes the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'NAudio.MmException' occurred in NAudio.dll. Additional information: WaveBadFormat calling waveOutOpen.

Is the code the correct strategy for playing a WAV with a custom codec? I have tried all four combinations of commenting out/in Lines A and B (with no difference to the error message).

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010 professional (project is set to x86), and version 1.6 of NAudio. I'm very new to NAudio, but did get a few lines going that played a "standard" WAV (i.e. a file that did not use a custom codec).

Answer (score 3):

If you have got a WAV file then there is no need for the `RawSourceWaveStream`. You can play the converted stream directly.

```
var wsRaw = new WaveFileReader(txtFileName.Text);
wsRaw = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(wsRaw);
WaveOut woCall = new WaveOut();
woCall.Init(wsRaw);
woCall.Play();
```

Also, you should not be calling thread.sleep to wait for it to finish if you are using WaveOut. Try WaveOutEvent instead if you are not using this from an application with a GUI.

Comment: I won't be able to try this until tomorrow, but thanks for taking the time to respond. The code will run from a Windows Form application. Just one more thing, are you saying that I don't need to define and use a dedicated WaveFormat (for my WAV file that only plays under Windows with a propriety codec)?

Comment: the WaveFormat is already in the WAV file, so the WAV file reader should handle it, and pass it on correctly to CreatePcmStream, which will try it against all the codecs installed on your PC.

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. I tried your suggested code (but had to change the "var" to "WaveStream" to compile), however I got the following error on the Play() line: An unhandled exception of type 'NAudio.MmException' occurred in NAudio.dll. Additional information: AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamSize.

Comment: that's a shame. Probably best to step through the NAudio code in a debugger to find out whether the ACM codec is objecting to buffers too big, or whether it doesn't support calls to acmStreamSize at all.

Comment: Hi, and thanks again. I've figured out more about what is going on.

Comment: Hi, and thanks again. I've figured out more about what is going on. The error is happening in the AcmStream.DestToSource() routine. On the 6th time through that routine, the call to MmException.Try(AcmInterop.acmStreamSize(...), "acmStreamSize"); causes the AcmNotPossible throw in Try(). The interesting thing about it is that if I remove the MmException.Try(...) wrapper (i.e., just call AcmInterop.acmStreamSize(...) directly), I don't get the crash, and I hear audio. There is definitely a problem though, because the audio is very choppy (like it's fading in and out several times per second).

Comment: With ill-behaved codecs I often use the lower-level Acm classes in NAudio to give me more control over the codec. Also, WaveFormatConversionStream was written with CBR codecs in mind, and with VBR codecs, DestToSource and SourceToDest probably should not be involved.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will investigate. Is there a sample project that demonstrates the basic use of the lower-level Acm classes?

Comment: Have a look at the NAudioDemo project at the `AcmChatCodec` class

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that. I'm (pretty) sure the issue is to do with treating a VBR wav file as if it is a CBR wav file. Is there a code sample that shows how to handle a wav file that is encoded with VBR (or should that just fall out in the wash with the Acm classes)?

Comment: The issue with VBR is that you can't guarantee that a whole buffer will get converted, so the codec needs to accurately report how many bytes from the source buffer were converted. Then you keep any leftovers to be passed in again for the next pass.

Comment: Starting from version 1.7 onwards, NAudio plays my unusual WAV file with basic code:
var player = new WaveOut();
var reader = new AudioFileReader(txtFileName.Text);
player.Init(reader);
player.Play();

Thanks for the update.